# Paging 3 - Why does my retry footer not call my PagingSource's load method?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I've implemented Paging 3 into my app following a codelab and added a footer with a retry button via `withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter`:

```
recycler_view_results.adapter = adapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
    header = UnsplashLoadStateAdapter { adapter.retry() },
    footer = UnsplashLoadStateAdapter { adapter.retry() }
)
```

When I click the retry button in my footer's ViewHolder, `adapter.retry()` is indeed called, so the setup there is correct. However, this method never ends up calling my PagingSource's `load` method as it normally should.

My PagingSource (I checked that the `LoadResult.Error` is returned correctly in an error case):

```
class UnsplashPagingSource(
    private val unsplashApi: UnsplashApi,
    private val query: String
) : PagingSource<Int, UnsplashPhoto>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, UnsplashPhoto> {
        val position = params.key ?: UNSPLASH_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
        return try {
            val response = unsplashApi.searchPhotos(query, position, params.loadSize)
            val photos = response.results
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = photos,
                prevKey = if (position == UNSPLASH_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else position - 1,
                nextKey = if (photos.isEmpty()) null else position + 1
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
class UnsplashRepository @Inject constructor(private val unsplashApi: UnsplashApi) {

    fun getSearchResultStream(query: String): Flow<PagingData<UnsplashPhoto>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { UnsplashPagingSource(unsplashApi, query) }
        ).flow
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 20
    }
}
```

And in my fragment I do this:

```
private fun searchPhotos(query: String) {
    searchJob?.cancel()
    searchJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.searchPhotos(query).collectLatest {
            adapter.submitData(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly the retry button for an empty list works:

```
retry_button.setOnClickListener {
    adapter.retry()
    // this works
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now after I updated the paging dependency from '3.0.0-alpha02' to '3.0.0-alpha03'. Looks like this was a bug in the library.

Afterward I also found the corresponding bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160194384